# Why is TFS not updating my project?

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core-mvc

We have an ASP.Net MVC Core project solution in TFS.

And there is an error icon at the top of the solution explorer that says "Package restore failed".
And if I open up the project.json I see the red sqigglies:
"The dependency ... could not be resolved" for several dependencies.

The developer who created this error has since fixed it.  And all the other developers on the team get latest and the error goes away.
But it won't go away for me.
I get latest and the error icon at the top of the solution explorer and the errors within the project.json are still there.

I blew away the folder, got latest from Team Explorer, and the errors are still there while gone for the other errors.

Anyone know why this is happening?
I'm stumped.  I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Long shot, but have you installed the Runtime the project is using? Is it 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.2, 2.0 Preview 1, 2.0 Preview 2, ...? You can check the version you have installed using the command `dotnet --version`, and check the project version on the dependencies.

Comment: Turns out I think its not a TFS problem but somehow I am not running the same environment for a windows project in the solution.
So  the comment above may be on the right track.

Comment: I stumped on a error with the same text simply by updating nugget packages. At first, the packages that were updated didn't had any major version changes, but after viewing history on the TFS noticed the update were the .NET Core packages, from 2.0 Preview 1 to Preview 2. Downloaded runtime update, executed, closed and reopened VS, and everything back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try to do a force update for the specific error fixed changeset.

> To force a update, use the "Get Specific Version" command with the
>   "Overwrite all... " option checked.

You could also [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), delete old workspace(back up changes first), create a new one, then do a fresh getting latest files from TFS source control. Which should do the trick.

If the issue still exist, you will have to check your local environment if you are missing some thing. Do a simply compare of the environment with other developers on the team.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a combination of the way .Net Core stores nugget packages and of being in a government environment.

We log into our computer with one account that does not have admin priveledges and this is the one I develop with in order to connect to TFS.  But there seems to be a lock on the users folder for this account.  So when I start up the solution and project.json tries to resolve all the packages, if one is missing it can't download it and put it in that folder.  I then have to start Visual Studio as an Admin and open the project.  Then the missing package is downloaded to the nugget package folder under my Admin user's folder.  Then I read the resolution failure output at the top of the solution explorer next the the red circle with the X in it to see which package is missing and copy it over.  It may be more than one so you have to close VS open back up as the non admin account and look for the next one that fails.